# How to use BackgroundScheduler with shutdown(wait=False) to exit

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

Using `python v3.6.6`, `apscheduler v3.6.3` `BackgroundScheduler` and persistent storage.

Trying to shutdown the BackgroundScheduler without it waiting for the running job to complete. Added the "wait=False" but main() still doesn't exit.

Slightly modified the documentation example https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/3.x/examples/schedulers/background.py as below and it shows a similar behavior:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os
import logging

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())
    time.sleep(1000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    scheduler.start()
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
        # This is here to simulate application activity (which keeps the main thread alive).
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        # Not strictly necessary if daemonic mode is enabled but should be done if possible
        scheduler.shutdown(wait=False)
    print("END.", flush=True)
```

Enabled APScheduler debug messages and it shows that the scheduler is still looking for jobs to run after it had been shutdown.

```
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Added job "tick" to job store "default"
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Scheduler started
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Looking for jobs to run
Press Ctrl+C to exit
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Next wakeup is due at 2021-09-29 16:05:18.200118-07:00 (in 2.998249 seconds)
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Looking for jobs to run
INFO:apscheduler.executors.default:Running job "tick (trigger: interval[0:00:03], next run at: 2021-09-29 16:05:18 PDT)" (scheduled at 2021-09-29 16:05:18.200118-07:00)
Tick! The time is: 2021-09-29 16:05:18.201439
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Next wakeup is due at 2021-09-29 16:05:21.200118-07:00 (in 2.999420 seconds)
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Looking for jobs to run
WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job "tick (trigger: interval[0:00:03], next run at: 2021-09-29 16:05:21 PDT)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Next wakeup is due at 2021-09-29 16:05:24.200118-07:00 (in 2.998518 seconds)
^CINFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Scheduler has been shut down
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Looking for jobs to run
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:No jobs; waiting until a job is added
END.
^CError in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..../python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 40, in _python_exit
    t.join()
  File "..../python3.6/threading.py", line 1056, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "..../python3.6/threading.py", line 1072, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

When debugging the original code, seems that at the end of the main() those threads (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1, ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3..) are still alive and waiting for join()

Not sure why wait=False didn't help here. Is the usage of "wait=False" correct?

Comment: Could you build a reproducing script and paste it here? Also, have you tried with the latest release?

Comment: @AlexGrönholm. I've edited the question, and pasted an example script and its output. Tried apscheduler v3.8.0 and ran into the same behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Also tried more recent Python v3.8.10 but same behavior.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm Is there any more information that I could provide to help? Thanks.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this. You should report this on the APScheduler issue tracker.

Comment: I tried this exact code again and it works fine. You still haven't created an issue on the bug tracker so did you solve this on your end?

Comment: @AlexGrönholm, That's interesting. The issue is still outstanding on my end. Sorry for the delay, I've created issue #567 on the bug tracker now.